# Xmonad Xsession

Tags: lightdm, window-manager, autostart, xmonad

My user level: noob-ish, so please bear with me

I'm running 12.04 LTS. I have installed and, to some extent, configured xmonad 0.10

The "automagically" created xsession for it works fine as it is, but when I login it won't run a startup script I've created and "call from" `/usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop`, if that's right. I've read pretty much all I could find about .xinitrc and .xsession, I tried that and it somehow messed up the other "sessions", if I'm explaining myself correctly. Had to `$unity --reset` to have the "main session" working again.

Anyway, my question is, how do I autostart xmobar and set a desktop background after login into xmonad's default Xsession?

I tried this script, start-xmonad:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#I only used one of the following each time I tried, none worked
#Also, do I really need the '&'? I know what they're for, but...
nitrogen --restore &
feh --bg-scale ~/Pictures/picture.png &

#Then I want xmobar to start, again do I need the '&'? I know it's for it to run
#in the background, but I tried removing the '&' and xmonad still launched
xmobar &

#Finally, the only thing that seems to work in this script
exec xmonad
```

Yes, I made sure I did `chomd +x ~/start-xmonad`

The xmonad.desktop is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XMonad
Encoding=UTF-8
Comment=Lightweight tiling window manager
Exec=/home/myusername/start-xmonad
Icon=custom_xmonad_badge.png
Type=XSession
```

So, this didn't work, now I'm here. Please help :s thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im a debian user but it should be the same solution for you:

I solved it like this:

(Notice .sh ending)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XMonad
Encoding=UTF-8
Comment=Lightweight tiling window manager
Exec=/home/myusername/start-xmonad.sh
Icon=custom_xmonad_badge.png
Type=XSession
```

Then i made created the start-xmonad.sh file in the home folder. Commands in this file should be runnable in your terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
yourStartUpApplication &
xmobar &
xmonad
```

Make sure that start-xmonad.sh has correct rights by using

```
chmod 755 /home/myusername/start-xmonad.sh
```

---

**Note**: & sign is used to run another command after.

---

Hope this helps! (: